# Updating DDL in Live Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to Update DDL in table where new column needs to be updated and old column has to be removed. Iam thinking of a stored procedure to do this. But Since the Production Database(Oracle) Contains Millions of Records i am thinking of using Nested Transactions within stored procedure. How to do it?

Comment: Also i need to Revert back data in case if rows would be dropped.

Comment: one wild idea would be to engineer this as a star object, where droppable dimensions are added and removed from a joining view, containing the main key. This way there is no overhead of losing a million-value column or adding another one. Also, you can retain the old column-object for historical or recovery purposes as well.

Comment: no the requirement is to persist value in db and not in a view

Comment: "How to do it" is not always an appropriate question in this site. Restrict your question to a specific problem. i.e  part of the procedure block, a query or an error that you are facing while implementing it . We will try to help you in such cases. For other specific non-coding requirements such as when it is related to administration, you may ask it in dba.stackexchange.com. A simple google search for the requirement would also yield several techniques for you to choose from.

Comment: What is a "nested transaction"? Or what is a batch transaction?

Comment: @vanun, you do know that views reside *in* the database, right?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should avoid using procedures to do this. Instead add the new column and use update to populate the new value. Then rename the old column or drop the old column or make it invisible. Rename the new column to the new column.

Comment: for update do you suggest adding it in batch transactions?? if not through stored proc then how??

Comment: bcoz there are millions of records in live db

Comment: Update using a single update statement and not in procedure..If it's a OLAP, you can do the update during downtime. Or you can create a new table with the structure you want and populate the data. Once you are satisfied you rename the old table and the new table to the old name. This has an impact on views if there's any . since they will continue to refer to the old table. So you have to update the views.

Comment: For ex:  update table table_name using(select column2,pk from table2 ) a
set column1 = a.column2 where column3=a.pk.. please check the using syntax

Comment: Take care when updating an added column - if you exceed free space available in the table blocks, you can create a very large row migration issue, which can have performance impacts.  Plus the fact you'll be locking the entire table during the exercise.  Consider looking at DBMS_REDEFINITION as an alternative